# Does someone know a 5 hour long or more film about an ancient egyptian like civilization?

Tags: story-identification

I remember being told by an acquaintance of mine about a really long sci-fi movie of sorts, regarding a team of modern humans somehow interacting with an ancient Egyptian like civilisation, which was ruled by a really advanced group that dressed like the Egyptian gods.

Comment: Stargate?  Fits everything except 5 hours long, which may or may not be snarky feedback.  If not, [here you go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_longest_films), precious few are genre.

Comment: Perhaps a faint memory of a Stargate SG1 marathon seen on TV?

Comment: @Radhil - Everything’s in some genre. ;)

Comment: If you are asking us, and not your acquaintance, how are you supposed to be able to determine what answer is right?